# How do you vertically align images within a list or a div?

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following code for showing some images:

HTML:

```
<div class="footer-logos">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="/sites/default/files/imagefield_thumbs/All Ears Cambodia Logo_1.png" alt="" class="first"></li>
            <li><img src="/sites/default/files/imagefield_thumbs/MLF rev.jpg" alt="" class=""></li>
            <li><img src="/sites/default/files/imagefield_thumbs/TAMTF A.jpg" alt="" class=""></li>
            <li><img src="/sites/default/files/imagefield_thumbs/unltd-logo.png" alt="" class=""></li>
            <li><img src="/sites/default/files/imagefield_thumbs/CECILYS HIGH RES.jpg" alt="" class=""></li>
            <li><img src="/sites/default/files/imagefield_thumbs/Street Child Africa.jpg" alt="" class="last"></li>     
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-logos {text-align:center;}
.footer-logos img {margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;}
.footer-logos img.first {}
.footer-logos img.last {}
.footer-logos ul {}
.footer-logos ul li {display: inline; list-style:none;}
```

This produces images that look like:

[alt text http://labs.dante-studios.com/footer-logos-normal.jpg](http://labs.dante-studios.com/footer-logos-normal.jpg)

But i would like it to center the logos vertically so it looks like:

[alt text http://labs.dante-studios.com/footer-logos-fixed.jpg](http://labs.dante-studios.com/footer-logos-fixed.jpg)

I've tried vertically aligning everything through CSS but that doesn't really work unless i'm using a table.  So anyway i can get the desired effect without using a table row?

**UPDATE 1**

The images that are produced can be of different heights, thus cannot use a fixed height css element...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do the images have a fixed upper bound as to their height?

If so you can set the `line-height` of the containing div to that height, and then set `vertical-align` property of the `img` tags to `middle`.

See here: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: He want to vertical-align the images, not the div.

Answer (score 2):

```
ul.seznam {margin: 0px; padding: 15px 0px 15px 15px; list-style: none;}
li.bod {color: #502945; font: normal 13px/21x Tahoma; 
margin: 0px 0px 0px 70px; padding: 0px 0px 2px 25px; 
background: url(components/bod_odrazka.png) left no-repeat;}
```

Comment: this is solution for vertical align image in list

Comment: That's a very weird sample code, but the concept is correct. Use a image as li background and apply proper alignment using image alignment and padding. One may also have to float his li in order to properly align text/images li elements.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.footer-logos img`:

```
.footer-logos img {margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;vertical-align:middle;}
```

That said, you should set a fixed `width` and `height` in each of the `<img>` elements to avoid the whole thing jumping up during page load.

Comment: Kyle's answer worked, but this one optimized it by removing the line height as the previous answer gave.